# What is the reason of EJB5123 error, rollback?

Tags: java, ejb

I made some task, and try to rui it each 20 minutes.

```
@Singleton
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class ScheduleControler {   
    
    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*/20", persistent = false)
    
    public void dailyJob() throws IOException, MessagingException {
     

    }
}
```

Generally schedule i working correct each 20 minutes. But after it after first run get error:

EJB5123:Rolling back timed out transaction [JavaEETransactionImpl: txId=8 nonXAResource=null jtsTx=null localTxStatus=1 syncs=[com.sun.ejb.containers.SimpleEjbResourceHandlerImpl@7a9c33ad, com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerSynchronization@3e4ede6e]] for [ScheduleControler]

GlassFish is set up for 0: `Configurations -> server-config -> Transaction Service -> 0`

Question is why is: why does it rollback, there are no errors in the code.

- Change GlassFish setting.
- Turn off Commit after each read in Hibernate.